# How do I center a graphic in the middle section of the Application Layout Control?

Tags: css, xpages, xpages-extlib

I've got several pictures that I would like to arrange and then center in the middle section of the Application Layout Control.  I've made several attempts but apparently am just too numb to figure it out.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to look into CSS.

For example, you can add a div around your images and then assign a CSS class to this div. Using CSS you can then center and control size etc. for this div according to your preferences.

Comment: I understand that part.  I don't understand how to find out what the class names are in the Application Layout Control.  Is there a graphic someplace that shows the Application Layout Control with all the classes identified?

Comment: Also, I don't think I understand the process of determining the class and overriding the css.  A book specific to Xpages and CSS would be an excellent tool for us old lotuscript programmers.

Comment: If you use OneUI as part of your theme, the following is useful documentation for OneUI: http://infolib.lotus.com/resources/oneui/2.1/docPublic/components/overview.htm

Comment: Also the browser developer tools are very useful tools when working with CSS - for example the Chrome Developer Tools which is part of the Chrome browser.

Comment: One of the web developers here showed me how to use Firebug today.  I made more progress in 5 minutes than I had in the previous month. Thanks for the tips.

Comment: Yes - Firebug, Developer Tools in Chrome, and other similar tools are very useful tools for web developers.

Answer (score 0):

I would say. Take a look at the [W3C Centering things.](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html)